# React execute a function at varying time intervals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an API which returns a list of objects. Each of these objects have a field called `timeOut` which contains some time interval in secs. Once the time interval of any object expires, some operation needs to performed on that particular object.

How can I achieve this in react ? I considered using setInterval on each object in the list, but it looks like a bad design.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use setTimeout instead of setInterval if you want an operation to run only once after the given time period. I believe this is your best bet to accomplish this task.

Otherwise, you will have to dive into even crazier designs like comparing the present date-time object from new Date() with the one you generated right after fetching your data, which will not only be complicated but also,  more error-prone and inaccurate.

Let me know if you want help with the first method.

Comment: I agree with the approach suggested, my concern is on having multiple `setTimeOuts`. The API can return 100s of objects, so we might end up setting 100s of time outs. Won't it have any negative customer impact ? @HittuDesai

Comment: Setting multiple timeouts is not an issue, it depends on how expensive its callbacks are. With small callbacks, you can definitely go beyond a 100 timeouts. You will just have to give it a try.

Comment: Got it. In my case the callback will be performing an API call. I have gone ahead with the suggested approach. Thanks for the help !!